# Aggregating values in one column by their corresponding value in another from two files

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, defaultdict, bigdata

had a question regarding summing the multiple values of duplicate keys into one key with the aggregate total. For example:
1:5
2:4
3:2
1:4
Very basic but I'm looking for an output that looks like:
1:9
2:4
3:2

In the two files I am using, I am dealing with a list of 51 users(column 1 of user_artists.dat) who have the artistID(column 2) and how many times that user has listened to that particular artist given by the weight(column 3).

I am attempting to aggregate the total times that artist has been played, across all users and display it in a format such as:
Britney Spears (289) 2393140. Any help or input would be so appreciated.

```
import codecs
#from collections import defaultdict

with codecs.open("artists.dat", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    artists = f.readlines()


with codecs.open("user_artists.dat", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    users = f.readlines()


artist_list = [x.strip().split('\t') for x in artists][1:]
user_stats_list = [x.strip().split('\t') for x in users][1:]

artists = {}
for a in artist_list:
    artistID, name = a[0], a[1]
    artists[artistID] = name

grouped_user_stats = {}
for u in user_stats_list:
    userID, artistID, weight = u
    grouped_user_stats[artistID] = grouped_user_stats[artistID].astype(int)
    grouped_user_stats[weight] = grouped_user_stats[weight].astype(int)
    for artistID, weight in u:
        grouped_user_stats.groupby('artistID')['weight'].sum()
        print(grouped_user_stats.groupby('artistID')['weight'].sum())



    #if userID not in grouped_user_stats:
        #grouped_user_stats[userID] = { artistID: {'name': artists[artistID], 'plays': 1} }
    #else:
        #if artistID not in grouped_user_stats[userID]:
            #grouped_user_stats[userID][artistID] = {'name': artists[artistID], 'plays': 1}
        #else:
            #grouped_user_stats[userID][artistID]['plays'] += 1
            #print('this never happens') 




#print(grouped_user_stats)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about:

```
import codecs
from collections import defaultdict
# read stuff
with codecs.open("artists.dat", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    artists = f.readlines()
with codecs.open("user_artists.dat", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    users = f.readlines()
# transform artist data in a dict with "artist id" as key and "artist name" as value
artist_repo = dict(x.strip().split('\t')[:2] for x in artists[1:])

user_stats_list = [x.strip().split('\t') for x in users][1:]

grouped_user_stats = defaultdict(lambda:0)

for u in user_stats_list:
    #userID, artistID, weight = u
    grouped_user_stats[u[0]] += int(u[2]) # accumulate weights in a dict with artist id as key and sum of wights as values
# extra: "fancying" the data transforming the keys of the dict in "<artist name> (artist id)" format 
grouped_user_stats = dict(("%s (%s)" % (artist_repo.get(k,"Unknown artist"), k), v) for k ,v in grouped_user_stats.iteritems() )
# lastly print it
for k, v in grouped_user_stats.iteritems():
   print k,v
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response, 'items' isn't defined? I've been trying to figure out what it is supposed to be or how it was supposed to be initialized and cant get it to work.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that, it was a typo I intended ".iteritems()" ended up by writing ".iter(items)"

Comment: Thanks! It's now reading:    artist_repo = dict(x.strip().split('\t')[::-1] for x in artists[1:])

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required.   Nevermind! Thanks so much.

Comment: double fault ... 1) I was expecting that the artists.dat file had only 2 columns, 2) as misread your code and thought that the data was "artist name, artist id", I was wrong ... instead of "[::-1]"(reverse the list) I've put an "[:2]" ( get the first 2 elements)

Comment: You're the man!!!!!!! The weights are off, but I can probably figure it out. Any tips on where I may need to debug?